# Separate and assign objects to variable from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have the following array that I need to loop through:

```
var arr = [{
  "id": 111,
  "wbs_name": "Mechanical",
  "parent": 'root',
}, {
  "id": 222,
  "wbs_name": "Electrical",
  "parent": 111,
}, {
  "id": 333,
  "wbs_name": "Systems",
  "parent": 111,
},]
```

My output should be like this:

```
 var mechanical = {
     "id": 111,
     "wbs_name": "mechanical",
     "parent": 0,
 },

 var electrical= {
     "id": 222,
     "wbs_name": "electrical",
     "parent": mechanical,
 },

 var systems = {
     "id": 222,
     "wbs_name": "systems",
     "parent": mechanical,
 },
```

I already tried looping through the array and pushing the object into another, but I don't know how to assign them to a variable at the same time (where the variable name is "wbs_name" and the "parent" is the variable name of some other parent object.

Comment: `arr.forEach( s => { window[s.wbs_name] = s; } )`

Comment: @gurvinder372 This is the code I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I have added the same as an answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though **polluting the global scope isn't recommended**, you can use the following

```
arr.forEach( s => { window[s.wbs_name] = s; } )
```

This code will create a global level variable for each `id` property of every object in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
var mechanical = filterList('Mechanical');
var electrical = filterList('Electrical');
var systems = filterList('Systems');
function filterList(filterBy){
    return arr.filter((ad)=>{
        return ad.wbs_name == filterBy;
    })[0];
};
console.log(mechnical);
console.log(electrical);
console.log(systems);
```

will get o/p as -

```
"mechnical"= {
  id: 111, 
  wbs_name: "Mechanical", 
  parent: "root"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare different variables on the fly, but instead you can have an object and assign to it's properties. Then you can get the properties individually using `object destructing`

```js
const root = {};

const arr = [{
   "id": 111,
   "wbs_name": "Mechanical",
   "parent": 'root',
}, {
   "id": 222,
   "wbs_name": "Electrical",
   "parent": 111,
}, {
   "id": 333,
   "wbs_name": "Systems",
   "parent": 111,
}];

arr.forEach(item => root[item.wbs_name.toLowerCase()] = Object.assign({}, item));

const { mechanical, electrical, systems } = root;
console.log(mechanical);
console.log(electrical);
console.log(systems);
```

Answer (score 0):

`var` in a browser is part of the `window` object. We can assign it dynamically like this:

```
window['my-arbitrary-string'] = arbitrary_value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign` and `array.prototype.map`

```js
var arr = [
    {"id": 111, "wbs_name": "Mechanical", "parent": 'root'},
    {"id": 222, "wbs_name": "Electrical", "parent": 111},
    {"id": 333, "wbs_name": "Systems", "parent": 111}
];

var { mechanical, electrical, systems} = Object.assign({}, ...arr.map(e => { 
  var parent = arr.find(i => i.id === e.parent);  
  return { [e.wbs_name.toLowerCase()] : {...e, parent: parent ? parent.wbs_name.toLowerCase() : 0 } };
 }));
 
 console.log("mechanical: ", mechanical);
 console.log("electrical: ", electrical);
 console.log("systems: ", systems);
```